# Using Key(@) function to extract keys from an object in Ansible

Tags: json, linux, ansible, jmespath

I have a file `file.sub` which contains this `JSON` object `{"kas_sub.test1": "true", "kas_sub.test2": "true"}`. I would extract the `keys` and to get this: `kas_sub.test1 kas_sub.test1`.
When i try

```
- shell: 'cat path/to/file.sub'
  register: file1
- debug:
    var: file1.stdout_lines
```

I got:

```
TASK [shell] *****************************************************************************************************************
changed: [ansible4]
changed: [control]

TASK [debug] *****************************************************************************************************************
ok: [control] => {
    "file1.stdout_lines": [
        "{\"kas_sub.tes1\": \"true\", \"kas_sub.test2\": \"true\"}"
    ]
}
```

So it's not conserving the same `JSON format` because i would use the `json_query` filter.

```
     
- debug:
    msg: "{{ file1.stdout_lines| json_query(value1)}}"
  vars:
    value1: "@[?keys(@)]"
```

`keys(@)`function doesn't return anything

```
ok: [control] => {
    "msg": ""
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>*note: taking for granted you want to read a file on the target machine*</sup>

---

In a nutshell:

```yaml
- hosts: your_group
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    file_to_read: /path/to/file.sub

  tasks:
    - name: slurp file content from target
      slurp:
        src: "{{ file_to_read }}"
      register: slurped_file

    - name: display keys from json inside file
      debug:
        msg: "{{ (slurped_file.content | b64decode | from_json).keys() }}"
```

Comment: man you rock, it's working as expected, the `slurp` module resolved it. thank you for your help again.
Please could you explain why with the `cat` command the format changes `"{\"kas_sub.tes1\": \"true\", \"kas_sub.test2\": \"true\"}"`?

Comment: If you use `from_json` on your entire `cat` output (i.e. `file1.stdout`) it will just work the same. But it is a bad practice to use shell when you have a module doing the job.

Comment: i got it so just applying `from_json` will give the same orginal format `{"kas_sub.test1": "true", "kas_sub.test2": "true"}`.
Exactly using a module doing the job is better then shell module
Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

Given the file

```yaml
shell> cat /tmp/file.sub 
{"kas_sub.test1": "true", "kas_sub.test2": "true"}
```

---

Use [*jq*](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) (if you can). For example, get the keys

```yaml
    - command: jq 'keys' /tmp/file.sub
      register: result
```

and convert them to a list

```yaml
keys: "{{ result.stdout|from_yaml }}"
```

gives

```yaml
keys:
  - kas_sub.test1
  - kas_sub.test2
```

---

Example of a complete playbook

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    keys: "{{ result.stdout|from_yaml }}"
  tasks:
    - command: jq 'keys' /tmp/file.sub
      register: result
    - debug:
        var: keys
```

Comment: thank you so much @Vladimir Botka,`jq` is not installed i will install it and give it a try. 
I really appreciate it

Comment: It depends on the use case. Make your choice. You're welcome.